# How do you print numbers with certain conditions?

Tags: python, if-statement, numbers, range, conditional-statements

The question asks 4 digit numbers within a range that has been imputed. The conditions are that there should be no number 4, no multiples of 4, and has to include number 7 at least once.

An example would be:

```
start: 1069
end : 1074

1070, 1071, 1073
```

So far I only have this:

```
start = int(input("start: ")
end = int(input("end: ")

num_list = [i for i in range(start, end) if i % 4 != 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
def satisfy(n):
  " Conditions "
  if n % 4 == 0:
    return False  # no multiples of 4
  s = str(n)
  if len(s) != 4:
    return False # lenght is not 4
  if '4' in s:
    return False # can't have a 4 in number
  if not '7' in s:
    return False # must have a 7 in number
  return True

start = int(input("start: "))
end = int(input("end: "))

num_list = [i for i in range(start, end+1) if satisfy(i)]
print(num_list)
```

**Test Input**

```
start: 1069
end: 1074
[1070, 1071, 1073]
```

**Alternative One-liner from @Matthias in comment**

```
print(', '.join(map(str, (n for n in range(start, end+1) if n%4 and '4' not in str(n) and '7' in str(n)))))
```

Comment: I edited my question. I realized that I forgot to add an example of how the output should be.

Comment: @bang21-this produces the same list given the same start, end range.

Comment: Your code as a one-liner just for the fun of it: `print(', '.join(map(str, (n for n in range(start, end) if n%4 and '4' not in str(n) and '7' in str(n)))))`

Comment: @Matthias--great--added it as an alternative to my answer.  Extended range to end+1, since not clear what the poster intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
def liste (start,end):
    num_list = []
    for  i in range(start,end):
        if (i % 4 != 0) and ('4' not in str(i)):
            num_list.append(i)
        else :

            return False
        if '7' in str(i):
            num_list.append(True)
    if True in num_list:
        return True
    else:
        return False
testlist = liste(int(input('start:')),int(input('end:')))
print(testlist)
```

Input : 1077,1078
Output : True

Comment: Can somebody help me why didn't stackoverflow notice everything as code except Input and Output and how do I change this

Comment: You shouldn't name a variable or function `list` because you overwrite the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list). And concerning your formatting question: You have to format the code as code in the editor. I did that for you now.

Comment: According to the question with your input of `1077` as the start value and `1078` as the end value the output should be: `1077`.